# How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath

In my webpage, there's a `div` with a `class` named `Test`.

How can I find it with `XPath`?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string

Comment: The more general related XPath,CSS, DOM and Selenium Solutions can be found in document [XPath, CSS, DOM and Selenium: The Rosetta Stone](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/). Specifically, your answer can be found in the item *Id & Name*.

Answer (score 684, accepted):

This selector should work but will be more efficient if you replace it with your suited markup:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'Test')]
```

Or, since we know the sought element is a `div`:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Test')]
```

But since this will also match cases like `class="Testvalue"` or `class="newTest"`, @Tomalak's version provided in the comments is **better**:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' Test ')]
```

If you wished to be really certain that it will match correctly, you could also use the normalize-space function to clean up stray whitespace characters around the class name (as mentioned by @Terry):

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' Test ')]
```

Note that in all these versions, the * should best be replaced by whatever element name you actually wish to match, unless you wish to search each and every element in the document for the given condition.

Comment: with my suited markup? Sorry, I'm not sure what did that part mean.

Comment: It means that I gave you a generic non-efficient answer that should work, but because you provided no xml whatsoever I couldn't make it efficient so you would have to suite it towards your markup. And did it work?

Comment: @meder: More like `//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' Test ')]` - Yours will turn up partial matches as well.

Comment: Why don't you just do //div[@class='Test']

Comment: Because classes can contain more than one value

Comment: I'm surprised xpath doesn't have a shortcut/more efficient way to locate a token in a space-separated token list.  Anything in later versions of xpath?

Comment: I updated the answer to specify the that the element is a `div`; that is, instead of `//*[contains...`, it now specifies `//div[contains...`.

Comment: // div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' Test ')] 
is really a good idea, it will escape the case when you only want class 'Test' and class 'Testable' founded

Comment: Only the final suggestion with `normalize-space` worked for me.

Comment: Another option I discovered that works in XPath 2.0+ (didn't test 1) is: `//div[tokenize(@class, "\s+") = "Test"]`

Comment: @thomasrutter why the surprise - this is just a language made for XML, not the more specific HTML, and who's to say it's casual to use space-separated lists as any node value in XML. Tomalak's solution is a very viable one.

Comment: Fair enough.  I think Tomalek's solution is the most elegant.  Since my comment from 4 years ago I've done that kind of thing a number of times.

Comment: "the * should best be replaced by whatever element name you actually wish to match, unless (...)" - it should be noted that this advice is very context-dependent. It can be a *really bad idea* to use anything other than * in contexts where the CSS classes are specifically meant to identify elements, while the concrete structure (`<div>`? `<span>`? Whatever?) is subject to vary, think automated UI tests and the like.

Answer (score 223):

Most easy way..

```
//div[@class="Test"]
```

Assuming you want to find `<div class="Test">` as described.

Comment: The above syntax is a lot easier to use and is less error-prone. REMEMBER you need to have the DOUBLE QUOTES around the class to search.  I would recommend using the listed above. //div[@class="Test"]

Comment: Does this work for the cases that div[class='Test'] lies in deeper level?

Comment: @Jake0x32 Yes, it does.

Comment: @Jake0x32, that's because it uses `//` not just `/`.

Comment: Does it match `<div class="Test some-other-class"> too?

Comment: @JugalThakkar No, it doesn't. It requires an exact match to work but you can try //div[contains(@class,"Test")] instead.

Comment: This answer may benefit from further clarification as it doesn't really answer the OP's question. OP says "a div with a class named Test", but at no point it is suggested that "Test" is the _only_ class in the div, which is what this answer assumes. The simplicity of this answer is appealing, which could lure readers into trouble.

Comment: @OlliPuljula why in case "@class=..." and in another cases "@class, ..." . What differences in "=" and ","?

Answer (score 66):

The **ONLY** right way to do it with XPath :

```
//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " Test ")]
```

The function `normalize-space` strips leading and trailing whitespace, and also replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space.

---

#### Note

If you need many of these Xpath queries, you might want to use a library that converts CSS selectors to XPath, as CSS selectors are usually a lot easier to both read and write than XPath queries. For example, in this case, you could use the selector `div.Test` to get the exact same result.

Some libraries I've been able to find :

- For **JavaScript** : [**css2xpath**](https://code.google.com/p/css2xpath/) & [**css-to-xpath**](https://github.com/featurist/css-to-xpath)
- For **PHP** : [**CssSelector Component**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html)
- For **Python** : [**cssselect**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect)
- For **C#** : [**css2xpath Reloaded**](https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/css2xpath-reloaded/src/b607205a42b2cf2ea9206f9e214cb9fddd4cb5b4?at=master)
- For **GO** : [**css2xpath**](https://github.com/moovweb/css2xpath)

Comment: this is REALLY the only way to avoid issues e.g. if you have more than one class assigned!

Comment: How about `//div[@class[contains(.,'Test')]]`?

Comment: @user31782: That would also match `class="NotATest"`.

Comment: "The function normalize-space strips leading and trailing whitespace, and also replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space." - none of which should be a problem in the case at hand, as long as we're talking about "normal" whitespace characters (`U+0020`). Removal of other whitespace-like characters that are valid CSS class separators seems to be the actual benefit `normailze-space` brings.

Comment: XPath would be superior to CSS, which STILL doesn't have wide spread ":has()" support, if it weren't for making something as simple as a "element has class x" query THIS complicated...
Why the hell doesn't XPath offer a function that does this padding with spaces just to split it up again and then compare the entries?

Answer (score 27):

I'm just providing this as an answer, as Tomalak provided as a comment to meder's answer a long time ago

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' Test ')]
```

Comment: Sorry to bring this up from such a time ago but what about `concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' ')` to account for all sorts of white-space characters as well?

Comment: For a sake of curiosity - Why `//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' Test ')]/chid` does not select children?

Comment: @Fusion if you post that as a question, you might get an answer.

Comment: @bitoolean being Captain Cbvious is hard these days

Comment: @Fusion I was just trying to help. XPath is not an HTML-aware language. It's more generic, XML-only. I don't have any experience in it, but I think you're assuming you can just put the id instead of the tag. You need to select on the "id" attribute's value. So you need to think of the HTML document as XML. Off-topic discussions don't help people find solutions though.

Answer (score 10):

XPath has a **contains-token** function, [specifically designed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-contains-token:%7E:text=the%20XHTML%20and%20DITA%20class%20attribute) for this situation:

```
//div[contains-token(@class, 'Test')]
```

It's only supported in the latest version of XPath (3.1) so you'll need an up-to-date implementation.

Comment: XPath 3.1, per your link.

Comment: Yes, it was added in version 3.1. The W3C have a nice [3.0-3.1 diff](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-functions-31-20170321/xpath-functions-31-diff.html). I have updated the answer.

Comment: Not supported in python's lxml :( -- https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Answer (score 5):

Since XPath 2.0 there is a tokenize-function you can use:

```
//div[tokenize(@class,'\s+')='Test']
```

Here it will tokenize on white-space and then compares the resulting strings with 'Test'.

It's an alternative of the XPath 3.1 function contains-token()

But at this moment (2021-04-30) no browser support XPath 2.0 or more.

Answer (score 3):

```
//div[@class[contains(.,'Test')]]
```

This is what I am using in my current project and it works *smooth as*.

The dot `.` in the expression represents the value of `class` attribute of any `div` element. So you don't need to use `normalize-space` and `concat`. Note this might also select divs with classnames `XXXTestXXX`. I happen to have my searchable class as `infobox-header` and the page doesn't have anything like `XXinfobox-headerXXXX`.

Answer (score 1):

Match against **one** class that has whitespace.

```html
<div class="hello "></div>
```

```
//div[normalize-space(@class)="hello"]
```