# White space and selectors

Tags: python, scrapy

Try to use a selector on scrapy shell to extract information from a web page and didn't work proprely. I believe that it happened because exist white space into class name. Any idea what's going wrong?

I tried different syntaxes like:

```
response.xpath('//p[@class="text-nnowrap hidden-xs"]').getall()

response.xpath('//p[@class="text-nnowrap hidden-xs"]/text()').get()
```

```
# what I type into my scrapy shell
response.css('div.offer-item-details').xpath('//p[@class="text-nowrap hidden-xs"]/text()').get()

# html code that I need to extract:
<p class="text-nowrap hidden-xs">Apartamento para arrendar: Olivais, Lisboa</p>
```

expected result: Apartamento para arrendar: Olivais, Lisboa

actual result: []

Comment: There isn’t really a whitespace in the classname. In html you can give multiple classes to a html element by seperating them with a whitespace in the class attribute. This means the <p> had two classes: text-nowrap and hidden-xs. That might help you further debugging the problem. A quick search by myself led me to the following solution, didn't test it myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3881148/6511985

Comment: first check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add elements to HTML. Scrapy can't run JavaScript and you may have different HTML than you expect.

Comment: Thanks @StephanSchrijver for your help. That's the point: classname doesn't have white space. Now I need to now how to use 'response.css()' selector to extract classname with whitespace in it. Do my research about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this cases I prefer using css selectors because of its minimalistic syntax:
`response.css("p.text-nowrap.hidden-xs::text")`

Also google chrome developer tools displays css selectors when you observing html code 
This makes scraper development much easier
[image: google developer tools]

Comment: Perfect @Georgiy. That's the answer that I'm loooking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The whitespace in the class section means that there are multiple classes, the "text-nnowrap" class and the "hidden-xs" class. In order to select by xpath for multiple classes, you can use the following format:

`"//element[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2')]"`

(grabbed this from [How to get html elements with multiple css classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881044/how-to-get-html-elements-with-multiple-css-classes))

So in your example, I believe this would work.

```
response.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'text-nnowrap') and contains(@class, 'hidden-xs')]").getall()
```