# Using XPath to filter HTML by class value

Tags: html, objective-c, xpath

I'm fetching an a HTML page and try to get some of it's content to show it in a table view. Following the documentation I tried NSXMLDocument and NSXmlParser but could not get any of them to give me the right data back :-(

The page I'm trying to scrap is http://www.instapaper.com/u

The code I'm using is

```
NSXMLDocument * doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc]
                        initWithXMLString: data
                        options: NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML
                        error: &error];
NSArray* rows = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//div[class='tableViewCell']" error:&error];
```

to get DIVs with class=tableViewCell.

If I only search for //div I get back a lots of them, but filtering by class seems not to be working :-(

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help,
Miguel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you are trying to filter by the class attribute? then you would need to add an `@` to your xpath:

```
//div[@class='tableViewCell']
```

yet, i cannot find a div having this class?

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis. I thought I did try it this way... but it seems I did something wrong when I did. Now it works perfectly :-)

Comment: One further question... how would I do if the class attribute value is "tableViewCell someOtherClassValue"? Right now it only gives me back the nodes which only have tableViewCell as value.

Comment: you could use //div[contains(string(@class),"tableViewCell")]