# Selenium: Is there a performance difference between By.Id("myelement") and By.Css("#myelement")?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, selenium, specflow

I was writing some helper methods for our testers around the IWebDriver in .NET, and started wondering whether there was any point in have a method to get an element by ID when you can use a CSS selector to also get the element by ID.

I would assume that, in the end, a request for CSS "#myelement" will be optimised away to document.getElementById("myelement") anyway.

Is there a performance difference? Should we bother using By.Id and By.Name when we can use CSS selectors to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I think the only difference is that By.Id is showing that you searching through id, but when using By.Css("#"), you need to write more and to know CSS syntax, it's easier to read and understand By.Id then By.Css("#") IMHO

Comment: What browsers are you testing against?

Comment: Google Chrome (we do have the web driver set up for FireFox as well, but we rarely run it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`By.cssSelector()` is faster than `By.id()`.

The method to find elements using `By.id()` actually utilizes xpath:

```
    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
      if (context instanceof FindsById)
        return ((FindsById) context).findElementsById(id);
      return ((FindsByXPath) context).findElementsByXPath(".//*[@id = '" + id
          + "']");
    }

    @Override
    public WebElement findElement(SearchContext context) {
      if (context instanceof FindsById)
        return ((FindsById) context).findElementById(id);
      return ((FindsByXPath) context).findElementByXPath(".//*[@id = '" + id
          + "']");
    }
```

Where as `By.cssSelector` uses the CSS engine.  CSS is *faster* than xpath, ergo, `By.cssSelector` will operate faster than `By.id`

Comment: That is not actually correct: "The method to find elements using By.id() actually utilizes xpath:". The first if is actually directing you to `((FindsById) context).findElementsById(id);`. That is a construct that I do not understand as `context instanceof FindsBy*` (where * is any (id, css..)) returns true. They are probably handling some weird edge case here. Anyway, my current tests with FF do not show XPath being slower than CSS.

Comment: so I want to see numbers.

Comment: unfortunately - SauceLabs has taken down my citation.  A resource used to exist at: https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors  That actually had statistics and reasons to use CSS over XPath (Speed being one of them. ). They had since taken the page down and replaced it with what you see now. I don't think you'll notice any speed differences unless you have extreme-case selectors.  As in, using xpath's `//` descendent hierarchy multiple times, combined with dynamic searching like `contains(@attr, '')`

Comment: Also, with FF - they have a better engine than IE.  If you use some complicated XPath, IE will slow down.  Nowaday's, it's sort of irrelvant which one will do the best.  CSS though, IS simpler.  Take a [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975595/why-one-should-prefer-using-css-over-xpath-in-ie/14139380#answer-14165197)  These are the statistics i was talking about