# Traverse DOM with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm parsing an HTML DOM in C# with the `HTMLAgilityPack` library and would like to know how to  traverse the DOM once I get to a specific element.

For example, when I get to the `td` with a class of "some-class", I want to go to the third sibling `td` and grab the `href` of its nested `anchor`.

```
<td class="some-class">Content I care about</td>
<td>Content I don't want</td>
<td>Content I don't want</td>
<td>    
    <a href="http://www.the-url-I-want.com">Some Amazing URL</a>
</td>
```

Currently, I'm landing at the `td` I want via:

```
foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td"))
{
    HtmlAttribute nodeClass = node.Attributes["class"];

    if(nodeClass != null && nodeClass.Value == "some-class")
    {
        //Find the anchor that is 3 siblings away
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I would use HTMLAgility pack to grab the related anchor for the individual `td`?

Comment: So far, this works (but feels ridiculously clunky)...                     `HtmlNode siblingAnchor = node.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.FirstChild.NextSibling;`

Comment: This is actually reasonable code to get particular sibling node (if you can tolerate occasional `NullRefferenceException` if HTML changes). I'd recommend reading some basic XPath tutorial to be able to select elements more precisely/faster (i.e. `"//"` have to search whole tree for match and often you can narrow down search to at least some particular sub-tree, you can also match attributes directly with XPath).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The HTML should be static and if it changes, I'll be able to  validate in the output of the program. I'll dig into XPath tutorials to see how to optimize. Thanks again for referring me to the HTMLAgilityPack to begin with, btw :)

Answer (score 3):

Learn XPath and your job can be a lot easier. For example, to get `<td>` element having class attribute equals "some-class", we can use this Xpath :

```
//td[@class='some-class']
```

And for getting third next sibling `<td>` :

```
/following-sibling::td[3]
```

So your loop can be re-written as follow :

```
var xpath = "//td[@class='some-class']/following-sibling::td[3]/a";
foreach(HtmlNode a in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath))
{
    //Do something with the anchor variable a
}
```

BTW, safer way for getting attribute value is using `GetAttributeValue()` method :

```
var href = a.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

the second argument is default value that will be returned when the attribute not found.

Comment: This will have an problem if the `td` has more than one class (`td class="one_class two_class"`). Appart from that, it is beautiful in its simplicity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath handles multiple classes.

Comment: @JonP The post you linked contains useful info indeed. My answer just didn't try to cover every possible problem unless it is clearly reflected in the OP's sample markup, to keep this simple

Comment: I agree, keep it as simple as possible, for as long as possible.