# How to get element with multiple class names?

Tags: php, css, dom, xpath

I'm having trouble retrieving the nodevalue of a specific li-tag with four class names. It is the class name "b-programm_ended" that uniquely identifies it.

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile('https://tv.mail.ru/channel/1296/65/');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $classname = 'b-programm js-schedule_item js-remind_prnt b-programm_ended';
    $results = $xpath->query('//*[@class="'.$classname.'"]');
    echo $now = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Did you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string

Comment: [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)

Comment: @Ace, this isn't your real issue. Please see my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not your real issue.

Unfortunately, you aren't *ever* going to be able to find any elements with class `b-programm_ended`. I looked at the source of *https://tv.mail.ru/channel/1296/65/* and could not find any `b-programm_ended` strings. However, I inspected the DOM with Chrome and *did* find some instances of `b-programm_ended`. This means that class attributes are being created with jQuery, so your server-side PHP parsing will not find those tags.

However, when I inspect the XHR requests from the same site, there is some JSON data being pulled from

> https://tv.mail.ru/ext/admtv/?sch.favorite_event=1&sch.recommended_main=1&cfg.get=1&sch.main=1&sch.channel=1296

that contains the data you may be looking for, for instance:

```
schedule: [{stop: "2015-04-26 05:15:00", name: "Белохвостые гиганты "Тэкомати"", genre_id: "142",…},…]
    0: {stop: "2015-04-26 05:15:00", name: "Белохвостые гиганты "Тэкомати"", genre_id: "142",…}
    episode_num: "6"
    episode_title: "402-я серия"
    genre_id: "142"
    id: "36239842"
    name: "Белохвостые гиганты "Тэкомати""
    start: "2015-04-26 04:50:00"
    stop: "2015-04-26 05:15:00"
    year: "2013"
    ...
```

My suggestion for you is to use a JSON parser ([json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP) and conveniently pick out the information you are looking for from that data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://tv.mail.ru/channel/1296/65/');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$classname = 'b-programm_ended';
$results = $xpath->query('//*[@class="'.$classname.'"]');
echo $now = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

since the b-program can be a unique selector for the required element, try the follosing code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://tv.mail.ru/channel/1296/65/');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$classname = 'b-programm';
$results = $xpath->query('//*[@class="'.$classname.'"]');
echo $now = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

Comment: what is the encoding of the requested link? i think it needs some work around.