# How to delele tag according to its previous tag class value?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath

How to delele tag according to its previous tag class value?

**Input** :

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<p id="quarter-line-below1"><span class="dropcap-image-qc ><img alt="2014" src="243864_20.png" /></span><span class="dropcap-qc">2014 </span>has had some strange and negative commentary about publishing with HTML5. The comments appear to be focused on HTML for trade fiction books and the requirements of publishing genres beyond simple narratives seems to be ignored.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to delete all tags which contains `dropcap-qc` i.e. `<span class="dropcap-qc">2014 </span>`

This is done.

**XSL Code**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="//*[@class='dropcap-qc']"></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am creating above XSL by Python code. I get all deleted tag class names and then create XSL.

My **Python** code to get class names: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482435/how-to-get-count-of-every-column-value-of-table

I do not know XSL much.

**My question is, I want to delete  all `dropcap-qc` tags but this should be next tag of `dropcap-image-qc` tag.**

Can anyone help me to get correct **xpath**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone help me to get correct xpath?

Matching CSS class *perfectly* in xpath [is a bit cumbersome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath). The following simpler xpath should work to get the elements to be deleted assuming you don't have any CSS class containing `dropcap-image-rw` (like f.e `dropcap-image-qc-x`) other than class `dropcap-image-rw` it self :

```
//*[@class='dropcap-qc' and preceding-sibling::*[1][contains(@class, 'dropcap-image-qc')]]
```

Above xpath selects all elements having class `dropcap-qc` that is located *directly* after element having class contains `dropcap-image-qc`.

**more explanation about the xpath, as requested :**

- `preceding-sibling::*[1]` : gets *direct preceding sibling* element of current context element. That will be the element that is directly before current element at the same level.
- `[contains(@class, 'dropcap-image-qc')]` : validates if current element -the element returned by previous bit of the xpath- has class attribute containing `"dropcap-image-qc"`

<sub>I'm not familiar with XSL too, so I can't suggest anything on that part</sub>

Comment: up1 I wil check and let you know.. Thank you.

Comment: @VivekSable Sure. Updated my answer with explanation about the xpath. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me to get correct xpath?

The chrome extension [Selector Gadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) makes it quite easy to get XPaths. Just click on an element (or a selection of elements), and it churns out XPath or CSS selector.