# using selenium find the existence of element having multiple classes

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have following html element.
using selenium i need to find the existence of the span class my-icon .
Also findout the first div class is 'active'.Since the class contains multiple classes i was not able to find element by class.

```
<div class="inner my active">
    <div class="left-side">
        <span class="icon my-icon"></span></div>
    <div class="right-side">
        <span class="icon-connected"></span>       
        <button class="button manage">Manage Connection</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

1)Code used to find the existence of span class  `<span class="icon my-icon"></span>` it is not working and getting element is not visible.

```
 WebElement ispresnet = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'my-icon')]"));
 boolean os = ispresnet.isDisplayed();
```

Comment: Hope this might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath

Comment: For multiple classes you can use css & join classes by '.' In your case try-By.cssSelector("div>div>span.icon.my-icon")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably *wait for element to become visible*:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.active span.icon")));
```

Note that I'm using `div.active span.icon` CSS selector here which would match the `span` element having `icon` class inside a `div` element having `active` class. Either the way I wrote the selector, or the explicit wait should help here.