# Xpath: select div with an anchor descendant whose depth is unknown

Tags: html, xpath

Sample html:

```
<div>
  <div class="foo bar baz">                          <-- target 1 -->
    <div>
      <span>
        <a href="helloworld.com">hello world</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo bar">foo</div>
  <div class="bar">                                  <-- target 2 -->
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>
          <a href="helloworld2.com">hello world</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select: `div`s that: 1)has class name `bar` 2) has an `<a>` descendant whose `href` contains `hello`.

My problem is that the `<a>` tag could be nested in different levels. How to handle this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *relative descendant-or-self* axis (`.//`) to check `<a>` element in various possible level depth :

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' bar ')][.//a[contains(@href,'hello')]]
```

related discussion : [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)