# XPath contains returning IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, xpath

I am new to Xpath. What is the following piece of code checking for ?  Does it check for both these class "a b" when retrieving span elements.

```
HtmlSpan resultsSpan =  (HtmlSpan) page.getByXPath("//span[contains(@class,'a b')]").get(0);
```

Thanks

Comment: this might be useful : [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath `//span[contains(@class,'a b')]"` looks for a span with class that contains substring "a b". f.e. `<span class="ba ba"></span>` or `<span class="a b"></span>`
But if your want to get span with class "a" or class "b" should use 
`//span[@class="a" or @class="b")]`