# Selenium find all elements by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I used selenium to scrap a scrolling website and conducted the code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import unittest
import re

output_file = open("Kijubi.csv", "w", newline='')  

class Crawling(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
        self.base_url = "http://www.viatorcom.de/"
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_sel(self):
        driver = self.driver
        delay = 3
        driver.get(self.base_url + "de/7132/Seoul/d973-allthingstodo")
        for i in range(1,1):
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
    html_source = driver.page_source
    data = html_source.encode("utf-8")
```

My next step was to crawl specific information from the website like the price.

Hence, I added the following code:

```
 all_spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div")
    print(all_spans)
    for price in all_spans:
        Header = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]")
        for span in Header:
            print(span.text)
```

But I get just one price instead all of them. Could you provide me feedback on what I could improve my code? Thanks:)

**EDIT**

Thanks to your guys I managed to get it running. Here is the additional code:

```
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='productList']/div/div")

    innerElements = 15

    outerElements = len(elements)/innerElements

    print(innerElements,  "\t", outerElements, "\t", len(elements))

    for j in range(1, int(outerElements)):

        for i in range(1, int(innerElements)):


            headline = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productList']/div["+str(j)+"]/div["+str(i)+"]/div/div[2]/h2/a").text

            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productList']/div["+str(j)+"]/div["+str(i)+"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]").text
            deeplink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productList']/div["+str(j)+"]/div["+str(i)+"]/div/div[2]/h2/a").get_attribute("href")

            print("Header: " + headline + " | " + "Price: " + price + " | " + "Deeplink: " + deeplink)
```

Now my last issue is that I still do not get the last 20  prices back, which have a English description. I only get back the prices which have German description. For English ones, they do not get fetched although they share the same html structure.

E.g. html structure for the English items

```
     headline =   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productList']/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h2/a")
```

Do you guys know what I have to modify? Any feedback is appreciated:)

Comment: The XPath you have is only targeting one element - that XPath has been copied/auto-generated, so I'd suggest taking a look at the XPath spec & tutorials so you can understand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To grab all prices on that page you should use such XPATH:

```
Header = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'price-amount')]")
```

which means: find all span elements with class=price-amount, why so complex - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)

But more simply to find the same elements is by CSS locator:

```
.price-amount
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback