# How to get xpath of the given string

Tags: jquery, selenium, xpath

I am trying to write xpath for the given element.

```
<span editable-text="x.script" e-form="capture" class="ng-scope ng-binding editable">www.google.com</span>
```

I am trying something like

```
$x("//span[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' ng-scope ng-binding editable ')]")
```

which throws me error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are entertaining CSS Selectors, how about these? All of these should work

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[editable-text='x.script']"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[e-form='capture']"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ng-scope.ng-binding.editable"));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
//span[contains(@class, 'ng-scope') and contains(@class, 'ng-binding') and contains(@class, 'editable')]
```

or using CSS selectors simply:

```
span.ng-scope.ng-binding.editable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial XPath should work for getting the `span` element posted, given that you close the bracket for `contains()` function properly :

```
$x("//span[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' ng-scope ng-binding editable ')]")
                                                                           ^this was missing
```

However, the trick which combine `contains()` and `concat()` (as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604480/2998271) and some other places) meant to match individual CSS class. So the correct way to apply the same to match by 3 CSS classes would be as follow (formatted for readability) :

```
//span[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' ng-scope ')]
      [contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' ng-binding ')]
      [contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' editable ')]
```

otherwise, your XPath won't be able to find `span` element having the same set of CSS classes when the classes order is different. Anyway, matching CSS class is not a natural task for XPath selector. Using CSS selector as mentioned by @Amey, if possible, is the ultimate solution.