# Find attribute value among various other

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I have this XML node:

```
<app type="ponctuation">
<lem wit="A B C"> ¶ </lem>
<rdg wit="D E"/>
</app>
```

And I would like to display the value of the `<lem>` element if one of the value of the wit attribute is A (or B or C). My XSL doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:app">
<xsl:if test="@type = 'ponctuation'">
<xsl:if test="./tei:lem[@wit = 'A']">
<xsl:value-of select="./tei:lem[@wit = 'A']"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, to be more precise, it works if the value of the wit attribute is the searched one.

So I guess my question is: how do I say to the processor "do extract the value of the lem element if its own attribute value contains "A", among others or not"

I hope I made myself clear enough,

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is similar to the task of [finding element by CSS class using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath), so you can use similar approach here. Basically, you need to pad the attribute value with spaces and use `contains()` to check for a match :

```
tei:lem[contains(concat(' ', @wit, ' '), ' A ')]
```

The above can be used in the template like so :

```
<xsl:template match="tei:app">  
    <xsl:variable name="lem" select="tei:lem[contains(concat(' ', @wit, ' '), ' A ')]"/>
    <xsl:if test="@type='ponctuation' and $lem"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$lem"/> 
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative method that doesn't depend on appending leading and trailing blanks, assuming you can use XSLT 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="app[@type='ponctuation']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="lem[count(index-of(tokenize(@wit,' '),'A')) gt 0]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="lem">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This tokenizes the attribute value to a sequence of strings and then uses `index-of` to return a sequence of match positions, which in your case will be either one element, if there's a match, or an empty sequence.