# python lxml - simply get/check class of HTML element

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, lxml

I use `tree.xpath` to iterate over all interesting HTML elements but I need to be able to tell whether the current element is part of a certain CSS class or not.

```
from lxml import html

mypage = """
<div class="otherclass exampleclass">some</div>
<div class="otherclass">things</div>
<div class="exampleclass">are</div>
<div class="otherclass">better</div>
<div>left</div>"""

tree = html.fromstring(mypage)

for item in tree.xpath( "//div" ):
  print("testing")
  #if "exampleclass" in item.getListOfClasses():
  #  print("foo")
  #else:
  #  print("bar")
```

The overall structure should remain the same.

What is a fast way to check whether or not the current `div` has the `exampleclass` class or not?

In above example, `item` is of [`lxml.html.HtmlElement`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlElement-class.html) class, which has the property [`classes`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlMixin-class.html#classes) but I don't understand what this means:

> **classes**
>   A set-like wrapper around the 'class' attribute.
>
> **Get Method:**
>   `unreachable.classes(self)` - A set-like wrapper around the 'class' attribute.
>
> **Set Method:**
>   `unreachable.classes(self, classes)`

It returns a [`lxml.html.Classes`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.Classes-class.html) object, which has a `__iter__` method and it turns out `iter()` works. So I construct this code:

```
for item in tree.xpath( "//div" )
  match = False
  for classname in iter(item.classes):
    if classname == "exampleclass":
      match = True
  if match:
    print("foo")
  else:
    print("bar")
```

But I'm hoping there is a more elegant method.

I tried searching for similar questions but all I found were various "how do I get all elements of 'classname'", however I need all `div`s in the loop, I just want to treat some of them differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for *iter*, `if "exampleclass" in item.classes:` does the exact same thing,  only more efficiently.

```
from lxml import html

mypage = """
<div class="otherclass exampleclass">some</div>
<div class="otherclass">things</div>
<div class="exampleclass">are</div>
<div class="otherclass">better</div>
<div>left</div>"""

tree = html.fromstring(mypage)

for item in tree.xpath("//div"):
    if "exampleclass" in item.classes:
        print("foo")
```

The difference is calling *iter* on a set makes the lookup linear so definitely not an efficient way to search a set, not much difference here but in some cases there would be a monumental diffrence:

```
In [1]: st = set(range(1000000))

In [2]: timeit 100000 in st
10000000 loops, best of 3: 51.4 ns per loop

In [3]: timeit 100000 in iter(st)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop
```

You can also use [css selectors](https://pythonhosted.org/cssselect/) using lxml:

```
for item in tree.cssselect("div.exampleclass"):
    print("foo")
```

Depending on the case, you may also be able to use contains:

```
for item in tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'exampleclass')]"):
    print("foo")
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I can't use selectors though because I need `div`s with and without the class in the loop, updated sample code to hopefully make that clearer. `xpath` `contains` would be problematic in cases where the class `exampleclass-numbertwo` exists, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1604480/188159

Comment: @qubodup, yep, that was why I added *Depending on the case*.  Are you looking for more than one class or just that single class?

Answer (score 0):

You can elegantly use the [membership test operator `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
for item in tree.xpath( "//div" ):
  if "exampleclass" in iter(item.classes):
    print("foo")
```

> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do
>   define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is true if some value `z` with `x == z` is
>   produced while iterating over `y`.