# how can i parse html with lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have this html:

```
<td class="name-td alLeft bordR">13.10.2016, Thu<span class="sp">|</span>17:00</td>
```

I want to get a date (13.10.2016) and a time (17:00).

I'm doing that:

```
t = lxml.html.parse(url)
nextMatchDate = t.findall(".//td[@class='bordR']")[count].text
```

But getting an error,

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think it happens because I have a html-tags in `a` tag

Could you help me please?

Comment: How is count defined? What is its value?

Comment: I use a `for` loop, because I have a several `td class="bordR"`

Comment: How many results are there from `findall` and what is the value of `count`?

Comment: It's not a problem in `count`. for example `count=39`

Comment: I need a parse this piece of code, and get something like `nextMatch = "13.10.2016 at 17:00"`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the way you check for the `bordR` class. `class` is a *multi-valued* space-delimited attribute and you have to account for other classes on an element. In XPath you should be using "contains":

```
.//td[contains(@class, 'bordR')]
```

Or, even more reliable would be to [add "concat" to the partial match check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604480/771848).

Once you've located the element you can use `.text_content()` method to get the complete text including all the children:

```
In [1]: from lxml.html import fromstring

In [2]: data = '<td class="name-td alLeft bordR">13.10.2016, Thu<span class="sp">|</span>17:00</td>'

In [3]: td = fromstring(data)

In [4]: print(td.text_content())
13.10.2016, Thu|17:00
```

To take a step further, you can [load the date string into a `datetime` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
In [5]: from datetime import datetime
In [6]: datetime.strptime(td.text_content(), "%d.%m.%Y, %a|%H:%M")
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 13, 17, 0)
```

Comment: yeah, it works. but I need to get a content in `<td class="name-td alLeft bordR">13.10.2016, Thu<span class="sp">|</span>17:00</td>`

Comment: @zagazat wait, sorry, is not it what I've tried to answer? Could you be more specific about what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: okay. i have a html-doc. with results of the hockey matches. i want to parse it. so i can get info about matches in `<td class="match">Team1 vs Team2</td>`. but, i CANT get info `<td class="n-match">13.10.2016 <b>17:00</b></td>`. because of error `list index out of range`. do you have a telegram? could you chat with me find me `@zagazat`

Answer (score 0):

There's a method called [`.itertext`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itertext) that:

> Iterates over the text content of a subtree.

So if you have an element `td` in a variable `td`, you can do this:

```
>>> text = list(td.itertext()); text
['13.10.2016, Thu', '|', '17:00']

>>> date, time = text[0].split(',')[0], text[-1]

>>> datetime_text = '{} at {}'.format(date, time)

>>> datetime_text
'13.10.2016 at 17:00'
```