# Why does .css work with this Nokogiri object but not XPath?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Why does the CSS selector return the correct info, but the XPath does not?

```
source = "<hgroup class='page-header channel post-head' data-channel='tech' data-section='sec0=tech&amp;sec1=index&amp;sec2='><h2>Tech</h2></hgroup>"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(source)
doc.xpath('//hgroup[case_insensitive_equals(@class,"post-head")]//h2', XpathFunctions.new)
 => [] 

doc.css("hgroup.post-head")[0].css("h2")
 => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x6c2b824 name="h2" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x6c2b554 "Tech">]>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `case_insensitive_equals` does what its name suggests, it is because the `class` attribute isn’t equal to `post-head` (case insensitively or not), but it does *contain* it. XPath treats `class` attributes as plain strings, it doesn’t split them and handle the classes individually as CSS does.

A simple XPath that would work would be:

```
doc.xpath('//hgroup[contains(@class, "post-head")]//h2')
```

(I’ve removed the custom function, you will need to write your own to do this case insensitively.)

This isn’t quite the same though, as it will also match classes such as `not-post-head`. A more complete XPath would be [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath):

```
doc.xpath('//hgroup[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " post-head ")]//h2')
```