# How to change original match in re.sub

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7

I want to split text in my `html` using `<br>` tags. If the text is longer than 50 characters, I want to replace last space before 10 characters by `<br>`.

The text is in `<span class="value">TEXT</span>`

For example `<span class="value">cccc cc cccccc cccc cc c</span>`

Will became: `<span class="value">cccc cc<br>cccccc<br>cccc cc c</span>` so every line can have at most 10 characters.

I've created a regex for this which can probably find such tags but can't figure out how to extract text from matched group and then replace it.

```
snippet = re.sub(r'<span class="value">(.*)<\/span>', 
                 r'<span class="value">\1<\/span>'.(divide text using <br> tags)
```

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Nooo... do **not** parse, process, generate XML/HTML with regular expressions. Use XPath, XSLT, BeautifulSoup,...

Answer (score 0):

The replacement argument of [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) can be a function which takes a "match object" and return the replacement. You this you could do any transformation with the matched string.

```
def replace_text(m):
    return '<span class="value">' + divide_text(m.group(1)) + '</span>'

re.sub(r'<span class="value">(.*?)</span>', replace_text)
```

---

Note using an HTML parsing library gives much better control when the input does not just contain exactly the string `<span class="value">`, e.g.

```
import lxml.html

document = lxml.html.fromstring('''<html><body>
<span class="value">aaa</span>
<span class=value>bbb</span>
<span class="value-is-irrelevant">ccc</span>
<span class="value should-match-this-too">ddd</span>
</body></html>''')

# http://stackoverflow.com/q/1604471/
elements = document.xpath("//span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' value ')]")
for element in elements:
    element.text = element.text.upper()
    # do your "divide text" here.

print(lxml.html.tostring(document))
# <html><body>
# <span class="value">AAA</span>
# <span class="value">BBB</span>
# <span class="value-is-irrelevant">ccc</span>
# <span class="value should-match-this-too">DDD</span>
# </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will dived the span every 10 characters.

```
import re
snippet = re.sub(r'<span class="value">(.*?)<\/span>', lambda m: "<br>".join([m.group(1)[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(m.group(1)), 10)]), """<span class="value">cccc cc cccccc cccc cc c</span>""")
print(snippet)
```