# how to find xpath in css for the below html block

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

xpath 
"
   Census 2010 Total Population
2016 Population Estimate (as of July 1, 2016)
2015 ACS 5-Year Population Estimate
    "

Comment: you should not ask for how to do something. if you ask a question you should already have an idea: please read the ask question guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where is your html snippet?

Comment: this question is already answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath

Comment: <select onchange="selectMeasure('POPULATION', this);" style="font-size:93%">
<option value="DECENNIAL_CNT" selected="selected">Census 2010 Total Population</option><option value="PEP_EST">2016 Population Estimate (as of July 1, 2016)</option><option value="ACS_EST">2015 ACS 5-Year Population Estimate</option></select>

Comment: Good question!!