# XPath V1.0 contains() not specific enough

Tags: xpath

I have an application that requires me to find a XPath selector for an element and then see if that XPath can be simplified.

So if I have

```
<a class="abc def gh">
```

I may determine that the XPath

```
a[contains(@class, "abc")
```

is specific enough. The problem is, it also selects items with class "abcxyz",

Is there a way to select items with ONLY class "abc"?

i.e. I think it's clear but I want to find items that have a class of "abc" or "abc def" but not "abcxyz".

Here's a more specific example because I believe neither of the answers so far works:

```
<div>
    <span id="x" class="btnSalePriceLabel">Sale:</span> 
    <span id="y" class="btnSalePrice highlight">$20.40</span>
</div>
```

I want whatever XPath selector will select the 2nd span and not the first.

If I try

```
//span[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' btnSalesPrice ')]
```

I get nothing selected. Likewise with

```
//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' btnSalesPrice ')]
```

Comment: To clarify, I would use css selectors if I could but I'm constrained to use xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `class` attribute is a *multi-valued attribute*, you have to [account for these spaces between the values with `concat()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604480/771848):

```
//a[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' abc ')]
```

Note that *CSS selectors* have this ability to match specific class values built-in:

```
a.abc
```

I think you can see what is more concise and readable.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my added example? Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

it is better if you use `css` for this exact matches, specially with `class` attributes, in which case it would be:

```
a.abc
```

You can use different css-to-xpath converters on several languages (check [this one for example on javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-xpath)) and its transformation would be:

```
descendant-or-self::a[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' abc ')]
```

Comment: I don't think this works on my (added) specific example?

Comment: @TroyWray your xpath should be to contain `btnSalePrice` not `btnSalesPrice `

Comment: It did, ty and sorry, I had to accept the other answer because the //a is more concise and I believe, as accurate