# How to write an XPath or CSS expression?

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, webdriver

```
<span class="left-menu-title selectorgadget_selected" data-xpal="xpath-verify-selected" style="">Admin</span>
```

How can I write an XPath or CSS expression? I tried the plug-ins does not work.

If anyone knows how to click an item from the left-side bar after log-in to the site will be a great help. it does not click, the script fails.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//SPAN[@class='left-menu-title'][text()='Admin']") 
WebElement clickOnAdmin;

public WebElement adminClick() {
    return clickOnAdmin;
}
```

Comment: Could you give the HTML or URL?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple classes but you are checking `left-menu-title` only.

The case of a `SPAN` tag name may also be a problem [depending on a driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Xpath-In-WebDriver#how-xpath-works-in-webdriver).

Fixed version, using `contains()` (note that it is not an ideal `class` XPath check - you [need the `concat` and `normalize-space`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604480/771848), strictly speaking):

```
//span[contains(@class, 'left-menu-title')][text()='Admin']
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that at least in Python+Selenium `//SPAN` will return the same node as `//span`... Does Selenium behaves differently in other programming languages?

Comment: @Andersson yeah, really good point, it then depends on a driver's XPath support, updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: This is way off-topic, but you might find [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/780210/users-by-number-of-profile-trackable-badges-obtained) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

what @alecxe wrote is a very good pointer.

Usually when a website has a strong front-end code embedded with data+JS, you should use functionalities. Especially when absolute xpath does not work such as your case with data var on the front-end. "data-xpal="xpath-verify-selected"

[Guru99 xpath fonctionalities](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html)

2. also please verify if your application or website is not embedded with iFrames.
   if so please change iframe window.
3. if you can provide the stackTrace Error. I assume you are talking about NullPointerException or NotFindElementException.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared, the following code block must work :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class='left-menu-title selectorgadget_selected' and contains(.,'Admin')]") 
WebElement clickOnAdmin;

public WebElement adminClick() {
    clickOnAdmin.click();
}
```

> **Note** : As you named the function as `adminClick()`, assuming you want to invoke `click()` method on the `WebElement` **`clickOnAdmin`**, `click()` method won't return anything. hence you have to discard the `return clickOnAdmin;` statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying writing your XPATH as `//span[contains(@class,'left-menu-title') and .='Admin']`

And instead of just `element.click();` use javascript executor click. Like how it's below:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'left-menu-title') and .='Admin']")));
```

Hope this works for you! Let me know.