# HtmlAgilityPack parsing web data to select second attribute in Android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, html-agility-pack

I am parsing a website using HtmlAgilityPack for android in Xamarin. I know there is the first() keywords but does anyone know how I would be able to access the second instance of html text? For instance, I only would like to see "Arrival Predictions not available at this time" as shown in the app sample picture.

[app sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC7N5.png)

```
void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
    //stores site in a document object of HTMLDocument class
    HtmlDocument document = hw.Load("https://broncoshuttle.com/simple/routes/3164/stops/36359");
    HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul//li[contains(.,'')] ");
    string result = "";
    foreach( var item in nodes)
    {
        result += item.InnerText;
    }

    MyTextView.Text = result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I had control over HTML I would probably use HTML class like `error-massage` to make HTML markup more semantic and search with more precision. Currently you can use simple `HtmlNodeCollection` indexer or [`Enumerable.Skip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Enumerable.Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) Linq extension methods:

```
// errpr-message HTML class and SelectSingleNode().
HtmlNode error = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//*[contains(concat("" "", normalize-space(@class), "" ""), "" error-message "")]");
// HtmlNodeCollection indexer.
HtmlNode error = nodes[1];
// Linq.
HtmlNode error = nodes.Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

For more information check:

- [Semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) page on Wikipedia
- [Semantics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics) page on MDN
- [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath) discussion on StackOverflow