# Scraping from a div

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am experimenting with web scraping and I am having trouble scraping a particular value out of some nested div classes. I am using the .NET HtmlAgilityPack class library in a .NET Framework C# Console App. Here is the div code:

```
<div class="ds-nearby-schools-list">
    <div class="ds-school-row">
        <div class="ds-school-rating">
            <div class="ds-gs-rating-8">
                <span class="ds-hero-headline ds-schools-display-rating">8</span>
                <span class="ds-rating-denominator ds-legal">/10</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ds-nearby-schools-info-section">
            <a class="ds-school-name ds-standard-label notranslate" href="https://www.greatschools.org/school?id=00870&amp;state=MD" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Candlewood Elementary School</a>
            <ul class="ds-school-info-section">
                <li class="ds-school-info">
                    <span class="ds-school-key ds-body-small">Grades:</span>
                    <span class="ds-school-value ds-body-small">K-5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="ds-school-info">
                    <span class="ds-school-key ds-body-small">Distance:</span>
                    <span class="ds-school-value ds-body-small">0.8 mi</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to scrape the "8" from the `ds-hero-headline ds-schools-display-rating` class. I am having trouble formulating the selector for the SelectNodes method on the DocumentNode object of the HtmlNode.HtmlDocument class.

Comment: Share your c# code that is supposed to be scraping the div

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be having a trouble to write XPath to select the node. Try `//*[contains(@class, 'ds-hero-headline') and contains(@class, 'ds-schools-display-rating')]` with SelectNodes method.

However, this XPath could have a problem if the page your targeting would also have class name like `ds-hero-headline-content`, which `ds-hero-headline` can partially match. In that case, see the solution in [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this to extract `0.8 mi`

```
//div[@class='ds-nearby-schools-list']/div[@class='ds-school-row']/div[@class='ds-nearby-schools-info-section']/ul[@class='ds-school-info-section']/li[@class='ds-school-info']/span[@class='ds-school-value ds-body-small' and preceding-sibling::span[@class='ds-school-key ds-body-small' and text()='Distance:']]/text()
```

Then this regex to group data:

```
^[0-9\.]+ (.*)$
```

At the end you can use some kind of conversion to save distance to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following to get the 8. You can search for a specific span element with the class name to get the inner text.

**Note:** I used text file to load the html from your question.

```
    string htmlFile = File.ReadAllText(@"TempFile.html");
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlFile);
    HtmlNode htmlDoc = doc.DocumentNode;

    HtmlNode node = htmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='ds-hero-headline ds-schools-display-rating']");
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);

    // output: 8
```

**Alternate:**
Another way is to specify the path that you want the value from, starting from the div element.

```
    HtmlNode node2 = htmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='ds-gs-rating-8']//span[@class='ds-hero-headline ds-schools-display-rating']");
    Console.WriteLine(subNode.InnerText);
```

**output**

```
8
```

Comment: @Michael does this answer your question