# Get class from element with XPath in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

How can I get the number 45 from this HTML code using XPath:

```
<span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_45"></span>
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
$rating = $xp->query('//span[@class="ui_bubble_rating"]');
$datas[$activity]['rating'] = $rating->item(0)->getAttribute('class');
```

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your @class is looking for a direct match of `class="ui_bubble_rating"`

You may have to use the `contains()` function to search within the string

```
//span[contains(@class,'ui_bubble_rating')]
```

Comment: Can I use this after `$datas[$activity]['rating'] = $rating->item(0)->getAttribute('class');` ?

Comment: Yes, that aspect won't change but remember it gets the whole class value, so you may need to `explode()` it on the space character

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the following XPath, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath):

```
//span[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " ui_bubble_rating ")]
```

You can then retrieve the number you're looking for with a regular expression that looks for a series of digits preceded by `bubble_`:

```
$ratingsElements = $xp->query('//span[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " ui_bubble_rating ")]');

if ($ratingsElements->length > 0) {
  $firstRatingElement = $ratingsElements->item(0);
  if (preg_match('/(?<=\bbubble_)\d+/', $firstRatingElement->getAttribute('class'), $matches)) {
    $datas[$activity]['rating'] = $matches[0];  // 45
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/G0VM7)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, this should work:

```
$rating = $xp->query('//span[contains(@class,"ui_bubble_rating")]/@class');
echo explode(" bubble_",$rating[0]->textContent)[1];
```

Output:

```
45
```