# Finding an element whose Xpath is unique to each login

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webautomation

I am coding a python web automation selenium script.

In the script, I use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')` to find elements on Binary.com. This means I would have to preload Binary.com and copy xpaths of the elements I need to find. For most elements the method works but for a few I realised that the Xpath is unique to each login.

For example, if I login in now and try to copy the xpath of a certain element it will be `//*[@id="tp1602844250562"]` but if the page is reloaded or I try to login on a different window the xpath would have then changed to `//*[@id="tp1602844157070"]`. Please note they are not the same id numbers. This means I cannot use one xpath on a separate page login

The desired element has an HTML code:

```html
<input type="text" class="time hasTimepicker" tab-index="-1" value="00:00" readonly="" id="tp1602844157070">
```

Refer to the supplied image for clear html code[image: html code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below with class instead of id as the id is getting pulled from DB i guess-

```
//div[@class='date-time']//input[contains(@class,'time')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the `class` instead of the `id`? Try this `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class = "time hasTimepicker"]')
```

Comment: This is not the best way to filter on class names. Please have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath/1604480#1604480.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your xpath expression to

```
//input[starts-with(@id,"tp")]
```

or, if it's not always `input`

```
//*[starts-with(@id,"tp")]
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the input element with that class use.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.time.hasTimepicker")
```