# get data from html using HtmlAgilityPack in c#

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

i have this Structure:

```html
<div _ngcontent-bxt-c141="" xlcell="6" data-header="Bonus" class="ts-table-row-item xlformatNumber">
                        <span _ngcontent-bxt-c141="" class="ts-num">9,000.00</span>
                      </div>
```

I tried this code :

```
var value = doc.DocumentNode
     .SelectNodes("//span[@class='ts-num']")
           .First();
        Console.WriteLine(value.InnerText);
```

and I get null error

Comment: @FlyingV says here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25994077/5107490 that you must use double quotes. Maybe its your case even though its C#

Comment: [Your code works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DZE8Wt).  Is your HTML actually different than what you posted in your question?  Could you edit your question to include a [mre] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: its the same html

Comment: Brain Rogers Sorry for my late Comment!! I am new in HTML I don't want to get the value from String HTML if you under stand what I mean I want to get the value from web (UPDATED VALUE)