# How to select all the attributes that contain certain String in an XML Document using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Similar to [XPath: How to match attributes that contain a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string) but without using XPath. Is it possible?

```
<c BarFoo="val1">
   <d Foo="val2" someAttribute="">
      <e FooBar="val3" />
   </d>
</c>
```

Basically I want to select all the attribute values in the document that their attribute name contains "Foo", so it should return the values of "BarFoo", "FooBar", "Foo" (va1, val2, val3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
elem.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName.Contains("Foo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

My starting point is parsing the XML string into an XElement object.

```
var query = element.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes()
    .Where(attr => attr.Name.LocalName.Contains("Foo"))
    .Select(attr => new { Name = attr.Name, Value = attr.Value });
```

The result of that is an IEnumerable of an anonymous type containing each attribute's name and value.

```
BarFoo  val1
Foo     val2
FooBar  val3
```