# find xml element with multiple values

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree, findall, multiple-value

Can I use element.findall() from xml.etree.ElementTree to find an element with multiple values in a single attribute?

I can use this to find all of the div elements with class="day":

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

calendar = ElementTree()
calendar.parse("calendar-week.xml")

calendar.findall('.//div[@class="day"]')
```

or this to find all of the div elements with the class="first day":

```
calendar.findall('.//div[@class="first day"]')
```

but is there way to find all of the div elements with "day" in their class?  I can not find any docs on how to do this.  Is there a way to use regular expressions here?

```
<body>
   <div class="calendar-week">
      <div class="first day" id="su">Sunday</div>
      <div class="day" id="mo">Monday</div>
      <div class="day" id="tu">Tuesday</div>
      <div class="day" id="we">Wednesday</div>
      <div class="day" id="th">Thursday</div>
      <div class="day" id="fr">Friday</div>
      <div class="last day" id="sa">Saturday</div>
      <div class="clear-float"></div>
   </div><!-- /calendar-week -->
</body>
```

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string) with more examples like one from @stranac but none of them work with xml.etree.ElementTree.  Maybe xml.etree does not support all xpath options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked based on the xpath term provided in the answer from @stranac

```
from lxml import etree as ET

calendar = ET.ElementTree()
calendar.parse("calendar-week.xml")

elem_list = calendar.xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " day ")]')
```

Answer (score 1):

This xpath is how you would usually do this:

```
'//div[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " day ")]'
```

Comment: When I try this or the simpler: './/div[contains(@class, "day")]' I get SyntaxError: invalid predicate.

Comment: Thank you for the xpath example, based on it I figured out I needed to use the lxml module instead since it has full xpath support.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice you were using `xml.etree`

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction and was greatly appreciated.