# Can scrapy find classes from tag with multiple classes in python

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I want to know that if i ahve this div tag

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3" >  some stuff </div>
```

Then if i mention this `//div[@class='class2']`

Will it find it or it just only find with single class only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string), but you should use:

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' class2 ')]
```

*n.b. there are some online [tools](http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php) for evaluating xpaths*

Comment: so u mean `@class="class2"` is equivalent to `contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' class2 ')` so i can use any tag before that i mean //div[contains ...