# How to match on class attribute

Tags: xpath

I have a document that contains elements tagged with `class="iana-group-15 iana-type-1"` or `class="iana-group-15 iana-type-1 iana-type-3"`. I want to match all elements that have `iana-type-1` in the `class` attribute. CSS has the notations [[class~=iana-type-1]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html#matching-attrs) and [.iana-type-1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html#class-html) that are very useful for matching this.

With XPath I match with:

```
@class="iana-type-1"
    or starts-with(@class, "iana-type-1 ")
    or contains(@class, " iana-type-1 ")
    or substring(@class, string-length(@class) - 11) = " iana-type-1"
```

This is painful. Is there a better way that would make this as easy as with CSS selectors?

Comment: Why not just `contains(@class, "iana-type-1")`?

Comment: @oded `contains(@class, "iana-type-1")` would wrongly match `class="iana-type-10"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath: How to match attributes that contain a certain string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surround both with spaces. I.e:

```
contains(concat(" ", @class, " "),  " iana-type-1 " )
```

Or in XPath 2:

```
tokenize(@class, " ") = "iana-type-1"
```

Or just use css.

Comment: The `concat` trick looks nice. The XPath 2 looks strange but I do not use this yet. Thank you.