# simple html dom space in class

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

the following class I would like to reference using simple html dom

but there is 2 classes one

is

```
class="price"
```

the other appears to be `class=" price"`

using this code does not appear to find it

```
foreach ($html1->find('[class= price ]/text()',0) as $price_data2)
```

the source for the page in question is here

[http://www.amazon.com/Likeable-Social-Media-Irresistible-ebook/dp/B00511ONPG/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=1367741120&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00511ONPG)

Comment: Try `$html1->find('.price')` instead. Then fetch the text-value from the result. If this does not help, take a DOM Level4 compatible HTML library that offers [`DOMDocument::getElementsByClassName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname).

Comment: this just grabs the class="price" and not the one with 2 spaces

Comment: Sure, because by definition the class attribute is a space-separated list of classnames. This is explained in the HTML and CSS documentation. You normally want to make use of that when scraping HTML, so I dunno why this is an issue for you. You might want to extend the condition. Otherwise if you want to filter by the exact string-value of the argument, find all tags that have a class attribute and then filter against that string value.

Comment: You can also just use a library that parses HTML *and* offers XPath. In Xpath it is easy to search of a tag with an attribute containing an exact value. You might find some inspiration in [*"How to parse and process HTML/XML?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456) [PHP Reference Material]

Comment: A space in front of a class name should not be an issue. `  class` should be reduced to `class` automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath: How to match attributes that contain a certain string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 0):

An example with `DOMDocument` querying the class attribute value verbatim (with spaces around):

```
// configuration
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// input
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/Likeable-Social-Media-Irresistible-ebook/dp/B00511ONPG/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=1367741120&sr=8-1';

// processing
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$prices  = $xpath->query("//*[@class=' price ']/text()");

// output
foreach($prices as $index => $price) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", $index, trim($price->textContent));
}
```

Output:

```
0: $14.81
1: $18.38
2: $11.58
3: --
4: 
5:
```

Please note that the URL you gave contains invalid HTML. Therefore the simpledom parser might produce different results (or does not work at all) with the data provided. This is equally true for the `DOMDocument` object I use here, however, it is build on top of the pretty stable libxml library (not only used in the PHP world, but in very many other worlds as well) and it also has a `recovery` property which allows further control.

Comment: The expression I would use is `//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' price ')]` :)

Comment: @Jack: Yes, if the search would be for a classname, here it is for the attribute value verbatim.

Comment: I didn't find anything to support that assertion though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
$html->find('*[class*=price]/text()')
```

I don't like that `/text()` though because it's not real css.

Also note that you need to leave out the `,0` when iterating with `foreach`.