# Is string matches() supported in Selenium Webdriver 2?

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Dear Selenium Webdriver Experts,

I am wondering whether the string matches method in Selenium Webdriver is working properly with the following code snippet in Java:

```
if (property.findElements(By.xpath("./dl[@class='cN-featDetails']/dd[matches(class,'propertytype type-house']")).size() > 0 ) {    // line 229
```

Below is the xhtml webpage where line 229 is reading from:

```
<dl class="cN-featDetails">
<dt class="proptype">Property type</dt>
<dd id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_SrchResLst_rptResult_ctl01_EliteListingTemplate_ddPropertyType" class="propertytype type-house" title="Property type: House">House</dd>
```

However, this resulted in the following error:

```
Address: 28B/171 Gloucester Street, Sydney
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector ./dl[@class='cN-featDetails']/dd[matches(class,'propertytype type-house'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
[InvalidSelectorError] Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ./dl[@class='cN-featDetails']/dd[matches(class,'propertytype type-house'] because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "51" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR)"  location: "
```

I have also tried `matches(class,'propertytype.*$']")` without success either.

The name of class changes depending on whether the property is a house (type-house) or apartment (type-apartment)…..

Any suggestion on how to use regex in matches to check whether there is value / valid tree node in this property type element?

This code snippet is looking up [this URL](http://www.domain.com.au/Search/buy/?nosurl=1&mode=buy&&state=NSW&regions=Sydney+Region&areas=Sydney+City&sub=Dawes+Point%2cHaymarket%2cMillers+Point%2cSydney%2cThe+Rocks%2cCircular+Quay%2cCockle+Bay%2cWalsh+Bay%2cDarling+Harbour&ptypes=119,220,213,198,210,76,172,113&ptdes=House%2c+Villa%2c+Townhouse%2c+Semi-Detached%2c+Terrace%2c+Duplex%2c+Penthouse%2c+New+Home+Designs&from=350000&searchterm=2000).

I am using Selenium 2.25.0, Java 1.7.0_11 on Windows XP & 7 platforms.

Your advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: <dl class="cN-featDetails"> <dt class="proptype">Property type</dt> <dd id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_SrchResLst_rptResult_ctl01_EliteListingTemplate_ddPropertyType" class="propertytype type-house" title="Property type: House">House</dd>

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, the [`matches()` function is a part of XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches).

WebDriver uses the [Wicked Good XPath](https://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/) library that only supports XPath 1.0.

Therefore, your XPath expression is illegal and you should rewrite it to only use features and functions from [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).

I think you could simply replace the `matches()` call in your examply with [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains). That said, it's *not* considered a good practise to match class names via `contains()`, because `type-house` would also match `type-houses`. Also if you match for `propertytype type-house` and the classes happen to be in different order, they won't get matched. XPath doesn't know anything about classes nor about space-separated lists used in CSS. For more discussion on this, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string).

You should really use a CSS selector instead:

```
dl.cN-featDetails > dd.propertytype.type-house
```

Comment: Also, you're missing a `@` infront of `class` in the `matches()` call.

Comment: One way around the contains-matches-too-much problem is to use `contains(concat(' ', @class, ' ') ', type-house ')`.

Comment: Yep. Also, the classes-in-different-order problem can be overcome using `contains(@class, "first-class") and contains(@class, "second-class")`. Ideally both chained with the `concat()` and possibly `normalize-space()`.

Comment: Thank you to the detail answers from Slanec & Ross Patterson. I use if (property.findElements(By.xpath("./dl[@class='cN-featDetails']/dd[starts-with(@class,'propertytype')]")).size() > 0 ) {
because it is much simpler and is working simply by knowing that the class name will not be the other way round - typeproperty. However, I am interested in learning how the equivalent command in CSS but know every little of how it work. Thanks a lot again, Jack

Comment: @JackBush `dl.cN-featDetails > dd.propertytype` is almost the equivalelnt of your XPath right there. The only difference is that it matches the `dd` elements that have the `propertytype` class. It will work even if they have some other class, too. To match your XPath exactly, I'd write `dl.cN-featDetails > dd[class^='propertytype']`. [See this page for more info.](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)

Comment: I am looking for a CSS solution that could do what XPath 2.0 match() could have done, by catering for space between class name. Thanks so much, Jack

Comment: @JackBush I don't really get what you're after, the CSS selector I provided in the answer is the best thing you can do imho. But okay, the most literal fit for the XPath in your question is: `dl.cN-featDetails > dd[class*='propertytype type-house']`

Comment: @Slanec What happen when class="propertytype type-apartment" or class="propertytype type-unit"... I am looking for a generic CSS selector that will pickup the class that consists of propertytype and the rest. e.g. "^propertytype.*$" including space in between.

Comment: @JackBush Shouldn't this be handled by the new [`data`](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/) attributes? Anyway. `dl.cN-featDetails > dd[class*='propertytype type-']` matches what you would expect - any `dd` element with `class` containing `propertytype type-`.