# Syntax error in selenium xpath expression using regex

Tags: regex, firefox, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium 2.42.2 and Firefox 29,  what is wrong with this XPath expression using regex:

```
//button[matches(text(),'\s*ABC\s*')]
```

It gives the following error message:

```
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "<unknown>"]
```

Comment: Could you please share the reasons to unaccept the answer? May be there is smth to improve? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`matches()` is a [part of xpath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches). In terms of xpath support selenium webdriver [relies on the browser](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-selenium-2-support-xpath-2-0%22), which, in your case is Firefox, which, as far as I understand, [doesn't support xpath 2.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396966).

There are plenty of functions in 1.0 that can help you to overcome the issue.

For example, `contains()`:

```
//button[contains(., 'ABC')]
```

If the text is at the beginning or end of the string, you can apply `starts-with()` or `ends-with()`:

```
//button[starts-with(., 'ABC')]
//button[ends-with(., 'ABC')]
```

See also this relevant thread:

- [Is string matches() supported in Selenium Webdriver 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000703/is-string-matches-supported-in-selenium-webdriver-2)
- [What browsers support Xpath 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658799/what-browsers-support-xpath-2-0)

Comment: @Solver good point, thank you. As far as I understand, Firefox doesn't support 2.0. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658799/what-browsers-support-xpath-2-0.

Comment: @Solver also found [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396966), that is still open. This is probably a reliable sign of xpath 2.0 being not supported..