# XPath selector for matching multiple classes

Tags: xpath

I've been searching for the past 30 minutes or so, but I can't seem to an answer to how to create an xpath selector that will match multiple classes.

After reading this: [How can I match on an attribute that contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string)

The closest solution I can find is:

```
//div[contains(@class,'atag') and contains(@class ,'btag')]
```

However, one of the comment suggests that it would also match:

```
<div class="Patagonia Halbtagsarbeit">
```

What XPath selector should I use to select a div with multiple classes?

Example:

```
<div class="fl badge bolded shadow">
```

Comment: Have you seen bobince's answer to that question?

Comment: Which XPath processor are you using? If it supports XPath 2.0, `tokenize(...)` will be your friend.

Comment: To search for div's with a class of fl regardless of any other additional classes on the same element -->      //div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' fl ')]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest backing the xpath up to locate the div more specifically so that other divs with the same classes could not be selected instead. You can use FireBug's FirePath to get the absolute xpath.