# Grab/Get contents from a child tag from an rss feed

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, rss

I have tried getting the contents only of the `<div class="start-teaser">` from [this rss feed](http://www.autoexpress.co.uk/feeds/all) with the script above, tried with `xpath`, like this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html); $desc = $xpath->query("//*[@class='start-teaser']");
```

But it's not taking it. And I don't understand why.
I also tried doing smth like this:

```
$desc = $html->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->getAttribute('class');
```

But this returns only the class name. And i need the contents (text) of that div no the class name.

```
public function NewsRss() {
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://www.autoexpress.co.uk/feeds/all');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
  $htmlStr = $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $html = new DOMDocument();        
  $html->loadHTML($htmlStr);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
  $desc = $xpath->query("//*[@class='start-teaser']");
  $imgTag = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');
  $img = ($imgTag->length==0)?'noimg.png':$imgTag->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
  $item = array (
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    //'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'desc' => $desc,
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'image' => $img,
  );
  array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 3;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
  $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
  $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
  $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
  $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
  echo '<div class="news-row-index">';
  echo '<div class="img"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="'.$title.'"><img src="'.$feed[$x]['image'].'" height="79" width="89"></a></div>';
  echo '<div class="details-index"><p><h5><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></h5><br />';
  echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
  echo '<p>'.$feed[$x]['desc'].'</p></div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
echo '<a style="margin-left:10px;" class="view-all-but" target="_blank" href="http://www.autoexpress.co.uk/feeds/all">View all</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class value is `short-teaser`, not `start-teaser`; so use `//*[@class='short-teaser']` instead.

For matching HTML classes, also take this question into account: [How can I match on an attribute that contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string)

Comment: ah did not noticed the class, changed it but still not working right: http://pastebin.com/Ye1ssbcc. It now echo's only 1 feed instead of 3 it was.

Comment: also tried the ones from that question: `$desc = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' short-teaser')]");` none of them work.

Comment: Apart from a bunch of PHP warnings I cannot reproduce your issue -- I'm getting `$limit` news items. By the way, better loop over all items in `$feed`, but `break` after `$limit` items, did you think of what will happen if the site only has two items?

Comment: I have hidden them with display none. This would be temporary until i find exactly how to take the contents of a div for my case.