# handling deeply nested tags in xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, python-requests

Please help me!
I don't know how to select deeply nested tag to select the text
inside of it.
If someone would please help me by saying, how to do it in a single line with 
`xpath` query and please give me an explanation regarding the answer.
Below I have given a html code will anybody explain how to display the Hello world or whatever may be in that tags.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="deep">
                      <span>
                        <strong class="select">Hello world!</strong>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to tell us the exact criterion by which you would like to select the text. Is it given by the class "select", e.g. completely independent of the context, or does have to be in a `<span></span>`, etc. Also it would be nice if you included what you have tried so far. That's usually a good starting point.

Comment: thanks for the advice Marcus Rickert :)..Will include it next time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume since you asked for the `text` property the node you'd like to match is the strong tag (the only one with content).

If you are guaranteed only one `<strong>` tag from the document root and the level of nesting is irrelevant, the simplest xpath would be:

```
//strong/text()
```

To match via class specifically as well:

```
//strong[@class="select"]/text()
```

`//` will start from the document root, and `@` is an attribute match clause.

http://www.b624.net/modelare-software-uml-si-xml/laboratoare-an-3-is/xpath-cheat-sheet

Comment: Note though that this will only work if the `class` attribute is *exactly* `"select"`. It won't work for `class="select foo"`. Getting a behavior similar to a CSS `.class` selector takes [a lot more work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string).