# How to locate an element by class name and its text in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I am trying to locate an element by its class name and the text that it contains

```
<div class="fc-day-number">15</div>
```

there are a bunch of `fc-day-number` on the page with different values, I need the one with for example 15.

I do

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("fc-day-content")
```

but I also need it to be equal to 15 and I am stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fc-day-content' and text()='15']")
```

Comment: I get this:driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fc-day-content' and text()='15']")

Answer (score 4):

```
 fc_day_contents = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fc-day-content")
 the_one_you_want = [x for x in fc_day_contents if "15" == x.text][0]
```

first line puts all elements with class name "fc-day-content" in a list ( also notice how its elementSSSSSSSSS with an S, this returns a list of all elements by_class_name, by_name, by_id or wahtever)

second line, goes through each element and looks to see if it has the text "15" as its text, and returns it as a (probably smaller) list

the [0] at the end of it, returns the first item in the list (you can remove it, if you want a list of all the ones that are "15" )

Comment: I get error:the_one_you_want = [x for x in fc_day_contents if "15" == x.text][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: if u are getting that error, then that means, no elements with the class name "fc-day-content" are found in the first place

Comment: if u are getting that error, then that means, no elements with the text "15" are found in the first place******** correction

Answer (score 4):

For things like this, prefer to use JavaScript:

```
els = driver.execute_script("""
return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("fc-day-content"))
    .filter(function (x) { return x.textContent === "15"; });
""")
assert len(els) == 1
el = els[0]
```

What this does is get all elements that have the class `fc-day-content` as the class. (By the way, your question uses `fc-day-content` and `fc-day-number`. Unclear which one you're really looking for but it does not matter in the grand scheme of things.) The call to `Array.prototype.slice` creates an array from the return value of `getElementsByClassName` because this method returns an `HTMLCollection` and thus `filter` is not available on it. Once we have the array, run a `filter` to narrow it to the elements that have `15` for text. This array of elements is returned by the JavaScript code. The assert is to make sure we don't unwittingly get more than one element, which would be a surprise. And then the element is extracted from the list.

(If you care about IE compatibility, `textContent` is not available before IE 9. If you need support for IE 8 or earlier, you might be able to get by with `innerText` or `innerHTML` or you could check that the element holds a single text node with value `15`.)

I prefer not to do it like TehTris does (`find_elements_by_class_name` plus a Python loop to find the one with the text) because that method takes 1 round-trip between Selenium client and Selenium server to get all the elements of class `fc-day-content` **plus** 1 round-trip **per** element that was found. So if you have 15 elements on your page with the class `fc-day-content`, that's 16 round-trips. If you run a test through Browser Stack or Sauce Labs, that's going to slow things down considerably.

And I prefer to avoid an XPath expression with `@class='fc-day-content'` because as soon as you add a new class to your element, this expression breaks. Maybe the element you care about has just one CSS class **now** but applications change. You could use XPath's `contains()` function but then you run into other complications, and once you take care of everything, it becomes a bit unwieldy. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390680/1906307) for how to use it robustly.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I have to follow python since all the tests are running in python

Comment: You misunderstood. The answer I gave you is Python code and **runs in Python**. It's just that the **Python code** sends a **JavaScript script** to the Selenium server.

Comment: For whatever reason no find_element_by_xpath, find_element_by_class, or even find_element(contains[]) methods worked for me even when I told selenium to wait until all the JavaScript on the page was finished rendering, but this worked like a charm.