# Finding elements by class in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Okay, so I'm trying to find the 179 in:

```
<span class="totalcount">179</span>
```

However, for some reason:

```
maxpage = driver.find_element_by_class_name('totalcount')
```

results in maxpage being set equal to:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="2c241847-ac56-4ed5-bb0e-73b473833ce4", element="9f837b6e-e78f-4fca-87b8-4efcb463e5a3")>
```

But I want to get value equal to 179. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to locate an element by class name and its text in python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370554/how-to-locate-an-element-by-class-name-and-its-text-in-python-selenium)

Comment: Did you try my answer? If it was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `maxpage.get_attribute("value")`.

Answer (score 3):

`maxpage` is instance of WebElement class. Use `maxpage.text` to get content.

Answer (score 1):

The command `driver.find_element_by_class_name('totalcount')` returns a WebElement.

Such instance includes a number of things, like the position of the element, if it is visible/clickable etc. You must use `.text` to find the "value" of you element. Try the following:

`maxpage = driver.find_element_by_class_name('totalcount').text`
or `maxpage.text` and assign it to a string.