# Add specific class to img tags if missing

Tags: php, html

I am using Nette PHP (framework shouldn't matter), and I'm trying to replace parts of html with different one - if image tag has `class=`, it will be replaced with `class="image-responsive`, and if not it will get a new attribute `class="image-responsive"`.

I'm getting that HTML as a string, which will be saved in database!

This is my current code. It can find the strings, but what I need help with is replacing parts of the html.

```
public static function ImageAddClass($string)
{
    // Match Img with class="$1 (group 1 here)"
    $regex_img = '/(<img)([^>]*[^>]*)(\/>)/mi';
    $regex_imgClass = '/(<img[^>]* )(class=\")([^\"]*\"[^>]*>)/mi';
    $html = $string;
    if (preg_match_all($regex_img, $html, $matches)) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($matches[0]); $x++) {
            bdump($matches[0]);
            bdump($matches[0][$x]);
            bdump($x);
            if (preg_match($regex_imgClass, $matches[0][$x])) {
                $html = preg_replace($regex_imgClass, '$1class="image-responsiveO $3', $html);
            } else if (preg_match($regex_img, $matches[0][$x])) {
                $html = preg_replace($regex_img, '$1 class="image-responsiveN" $2$3', $html);
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions are not suitable for HTML. Try using DOMDocument and XPath queries

Comment: _"Im getting that HTML as a string, so it shouldnt be a problem"_ - that is absolutely not where the problem lies. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1427878

Comment: Im getting that HTML as a string, which will be saved in database!

Comment: So? Html is text, so it's always a string. So is JSON, so is XML, so is base64 etc etc. Doesn't mean you have to use generic regex to parse it. Use something which actually understands HTML, as suggested in the first comment. It's too complex and unpredictable to reliably parse just with regex.

Comment: HTML can have nested elements, with regexp you'd have to cover this with look-aheads or look-behind. Unfortunately, HTML can be nested multiple times, and you would need to cover each level in the regexp. In the end you won't find a generic regexp for any arbitrary HTML, but the regexp would need to be forged especially for a certain piece of HTML - which is clearly what a programmer doesn't want :)

Comment: I am voting to reopen this page because the "go away" canonical page closure does nothing to resolve the question of how to add class names to elements missing the specific class. It actually punishes the asker for providing a coding attempt. Researchers will turn away from Stack Overflow if specialized questions only point to a broad, mile-long canonical that is devoid of resolving advice for the given task.  This closure makes Stack Overflow worse.

Answer (score 0):

Covering all scenarios where an img tag might have no class attribute, an orphaned class attribute, a blank class attribute, a class attribute with one or more other words, and a class attribute that already contains `image-responsive` -- I prefer to use XPath to filter the elements.

Not only is parsing HTML with a legitimate DOM parser like DOMDocument more robust/reliable than regex, the accompanying XPath syntax is highly intuitive.

Pay close attention to how the XPath query pads the haystack class and the needle class with spaces as a means to ensure whole word matching.

Any images that are iterated will have the desired value added to the element's class attribute.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4OOnr))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
    <img src="">
    <img src="" class>
    <img src="" class="image-responsive">
    <img src="" class="">
    <img src="image-responsive" class="classy">  
    <img src="" class="image-responsiveness">
    <span class='NOT-responsive'></span>
    <img src="" class = "foo image-responsive">
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//img[not(contains(concat(" ", @class, " ")," image-responsive "))]') as $img) {
    $img->setAttribute('class', ltrim($img->getAttribute('class') . ' image-responsive'));
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <img src="" class="image-responsive">
    <img src="" class="image-responsive">
    <img src="" class="image-responsive">
    <img src="" class="image-responsive">
    <img src="image-responsive" class="classy image-responsive">  
    <img src="" class="image-responsiveness image-responsive">
    <span class="NOT-responsive"></span>
    <img src="" class="foo image-responsive">
</div>
```

Related content:

- [Replace empty alt in wordpress post content with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72799485/2943403)
- [Xpath syntax for "and not contains"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26640746/2943403)
- [Parsing HTML with PHP To Add Class Names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51384904/2943403)
- [How can I match on an attribute that contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1390568/2943403)

---

As a slight variation, you can access all img tags without XPath, then use `preg_match()` calls to determine which tags should receive the new class.  The word boundary character `\b` is not useful in this case because class names may contain non-word characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/78g8G))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $class = $img->getAttribute('class');
    if (!preg_match('/(?:^| )image-responsive(?: |$)/', $class)) {
        $img->setAttribute('class', ltrim("$class image-responsive"));
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
// same output as first snippet
```