# How to check if great-grandfather has class attribute containing some word?

Tags: html, xpath

I have a html code like this:

```
<div  class='one two three and etc.'>
    <div>
           <div>
                <div class='my_target'>
               </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I need to find div with `class="my_target"`  whose great-grandfather has class containing a word "two", for example. I tried an expression like this:

```
//div[../../../[contains(@class,'two')]]
```

but it doesn't work! Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to approach the problem from another direction. Use the following expression:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'two')]/*/*/div[@class = 'my_target']
```

which means

```
//div[contains(@class, 'two')]     Select `div` elements anywhere in the document, if
                                   their `class` attribute contains "two"
/*/*/div[@class = 'my_target']     look for any grand-grandchild named `div` whose
                                   `class` attribute value is "my_target"
```

and which will return

```
<div class="my_target"></div>
```

**EDIT**

If there is reason to believe that "two" will occur in other contexts where it should not be matched (e.g. `<div class='two-fold'/>`), then use

```
contains( concat(' ', normalize-space(@class) ,' '), ' two ' )
```

Thanks to Phrogz for this suggestion.

Comment: Great! Your expression works.  Thanks for your help @Mathias Muller

Comment: @AlexRixon You are welcome. Please do not forget to accept an answer, both JLRishe's answer and mine are correct, the choice is yours. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they are correct but you answered first, so I accept your answer )

Comment: Thanks for your remark @Phrogz . I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 3):

You were close. You needed to use this:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'my_target'][contains(../../../@class,'two')]
```

Note the parentheses around the `../../..` and the lack of a slash after that part.

Or since there can only be

But I would recommend this alternative:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'two')]/*/*/div[contains(@class, 'my_target')]
```

Note how it doesn't have go down the tree and climb back up again.

**Side note:** As Phrogz correctly points out, a more reliable match for class name is to surround the `class` attribute and the target class name in spaces:

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' two ')]/*/*
    /div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' my_target ')]
```

Comment: I have never seen such expression and it works. Thanx for your answer JLRishe

Comment: Note that this will incorrectly match `class="two-fold"`; the standard way of using XPath to match a word inside a space-delimited list is to [wrap the string in spaces and then test for the word surrounded by spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string), e.g. `contains( concat(' ',@class,' '), ' two ' )`.

Comment: @Phrogz Quite right. I'm usually more diligent about that, but I guess I was off my game yesterday. :) To be perfectly correct, you'll also need a `normalize-space()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//div[contains(../../../@class,'two')]
```

or to get `class="my_target"` elements only

```
//div[contains(@class,'my_target') and contains(../../../@class,'two')]
```

Comment: Only answers half of the question and there are already two very similar answers, one of them explaining why `../../../`  might be more costly.