# Not able to extract the name of the radio button from DOM using the xpath using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

When i pass `//input[@type='radio']` in the xpath, i'm able to select all the radio buttons in the list but i am not able to select a particular radio button by it's name.
Name of the radio button is the fourth term in quotes inside the render_selected_term list.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_190');render_selected_term('190','1','275464','AQCB Number')" value="190" name="radio_190"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_179');render_selected_term('179','1','275464','AQCB Number (iLink)')" value="179" name="radio_179"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_19');render_selected_term('19','1','275464','Acceptance')" value="19" name="radio_19"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_148');render_selected_term('148','1','275464','Account (iLink)')" value="148" name="radio_148"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_206');render_selected_term('206','1','275464','Additional Non-standard Terms')" value="206" name="radio_206"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_220');render_selected_term('220','1','275464','Assigned Contract Manager (iLink)')" value="220" name="radio_220"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_12');render_selected_term('12','1','275464','Assignment')" value="12" name="radio_12"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_188');render_selected_term('188','1','275464','Authorized Purchasing Entity(ies)')" value="188" name="radio_188"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_226');render_selected_term('226','1','275464','Award (iLink)')" value="226" name="radio_226"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_196');render_selected_term('196','1','275464','Award Amount')" value="196" name="radio_196"/>
```

Comment: How did you try to select radio button by it's name *exactly*?

Comment: I tried using contains. But that did not help my cause. So, i'm looking for other ways by which it can be done.

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj what did you use as your xpath for the name?

Comment: can you share the code how you did using `contains()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string/1390680#1390680
take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use css selector in this case and attribute search. Be very careful when you use the following selector. The match you are looking for has to be unique.

Note: I am not sure which match you are looking for. So, I am showing you an example.

```
[onclick*='148']
```

Should match `<input type="radio" name="radio_148" value="148" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_148');render_selected_term('148','1','275464','Account (iLink)')"/>`

Comment: Matching the value is working fine. But i want to match it with "Account (iLink)" as seen in the example you gave.

Comment: Then try `[onclick*='Account (iLink)']`

Comment: I've tried that too. //input[@type='radio' and onclick*='AQCB Number'] also is not helping me.

Comment: You are using xpath and I provided css.

Comment: Try this `[onclick*='AQCB Number'][type='radio']:nth-child(2)` notice it returns two elements and that's why I used nth-child(2) to get the second element. You can change it to 1 to get the first element

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="something">
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_190');render_selected_term('190','1','275464','AQCB Number')" value="190" name="radio_190"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_179');render_selected_term('179','1','275464','AQCB Number (iLink)')" value="179" name="radio_179"/>


    IList<IWebElement> inputs = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='something']/input)");


    foreach(var element in inputs)
    {
       if(element.getAttribute("name").Equals("radio_12"))
         element.Click();
    }
```