# xpath to select full content of the class except one sub child class

Tags: xpath, import.io

```
<div class="content" style="opacity: 1;">
      <div class="A" >
      <ul class ="any" >
      <div class ="demo" >
      <div class="pipe" >
      <ul class= "markedl-list">
```

I want to select class content except sub class "marked-list"
Any help?

Comment: Do you mean to select `<div class="content"...>` are the below lines children of the `<div class="content"...>` ? Please clearly describe the question , no one can guess here.

Comment: Yes i want to select <div class="content"...> but not <ul class= "markedl-list">

Comment: is `<ul class="markedl-list">` child of `<div class="content"..>` ?

Comment: Yes......................

Comment: If you want to  select `<div class="content"...>` you are bound to get the child `<ul class="markedl-list">` I think you are looking something like filter the xml element `<div class="content"...>` then you need an xslt. Xpath only serves as selector.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the elements you're trying to select are direct children of `div` with the class `content` and you don't need to select the parent "content" div, this xpath 1.0 should work...

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' content ')]/*[not(contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' markedl-list '))]
```

Note the possible misspelling of "markedl-list".

Also, the use of `contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' someclass ')` might seem like overkill, but will account for the possibility of classes other than the target class being in the class attribute. If you can use XPath 2.0, this test is much cleaner ([How can I match on an attribute that contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-can-i-match-on-an-attribute-that-contains-a-certain-string/12165195#12165195)).

Example: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/d449841c402b3e15ef69e3004a39ee6c