# Names from a webpage are not getting scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

Running my scraper I could see that it fetches nothing from yell.com. So far I know Xpaths are alright. Can't really find out whether I've made any mistakes. Hope there is any workaround. I tried with the below code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=pizza&location=all+states&scrambleSeed=821749505"
def Startpoint(address):
    response = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"col-sm-24")]')
    for title in titles:
        try:
            Name=title.xpath('.//h2[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0]
            print(Name)
        except exception as e:
            print(e.message)
            continue
Startpoint(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `User-Agent` string *pretending to be a real browser*:

```
response = requests.get(address, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'})
```

Some other notes:

- `Exception` starts with an upper case letter
- you should not be using `col-sm-24` class inside your locator - this kind of bootstrap class is *layout-specific* and does not really bring any data container specific type of information. Use `businessCapsule` class instead:

  ```
  titles = tree.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' businessCapsule ')]")
  ```

  Note how we [properly check the class attribute here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390680/771848).
- you can use `findtext()` method to find the result titles:

  ```
  results = tree.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' businessCapsule ')]")

  for result in results:
      name = result.findtext('.//h2[@itemprop="name"]')
      print(name)
  ```

Comment: You are just awesome, sir alecxe. Every time you touch on my messy code it works like magic. Gonna accept it in a while.

Comment: Findtext method is quite new to me. It works perfectly. Is this "findtext" method applicable for extracting "href" as well?

Comment: @SMth80 nope, `findtext()` is only about the text of a node. Thanks.