# DomxPath query do not return a nodelist

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I've been working on some practice application involving xPaths and Retrieving elements from other website.

I used DomXpath for it but it is not returning a result or nodelist.

Here's the code:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
@$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//span[contains(@style,'font-size:25px;')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

The page source of the example:

```
    <div class="front-view-content full-post">
    <p>
      <span style="font-size:25px; color:#98293D;">RED</span><br>
      <span style="font-size:25px; color:#98293D;">BLUE</span><br>
      <span style="font-size:25px; color:#98293D;">WHITE</span></p>
    </div>
```

it doesn't return anything just a plain blank.

Answer (score 0):

There is no semicolon ; in the source, so xpath doesn't match.

```
$nodes = $finder->query('//span[@style="font-size:25px"]');
```

Should work

Comment: Style in the xpath query should be an exact match for the style in html code.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to match attributes that contain a certain value is a little more complicated than just doing `[@style="your search string"]`, as this will only match a `style` attribute that exactly matches `your search string`.

To my knowledge there's no shorthand selectors in xpath, similar to the ones in CSS for instance, that allows you to do `[@style*="your search string"]` or `[@style~="your search string"]`, etc.

To test if a string contains another string, you use the [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function. You're example xpath query would then have to be transformed to:

`//span[contains(@style,"font-size:25px;")]`

Be aware though that matching isolated strings, at the word boundary if you will, (such as matching the class `main` in `class="nav main"`, but not in `class="nav maintenance"`, for instance), gets a little more complicated, still. I'll refer you [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390680) for such an example.

Comment: It's not working either. I get a blank page result. I've used the xpath query that you've suggested

Comment: @GerardSantos Then you should remove the `@` in front of `$DOM->loadHTML($html);` and let PHP show you the actual errors, in stead of suppressing them, because, if the HTML you've shown is just a snippet of a larger page that is valid HTML, it should work just fine, because I've just tested it. If you're unsure how to successfully load possibly invalid HTML with `DOMDocument` I suggest you ask a new question or search StackOverflow; perhaps such questions are already answered.