# Why cannot I not convert this css to an xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to convert this css_selector  to an xpath that gets team names on this [site](https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer)

So: `match-pop-market > #options_table > tbody > tr#mta_row > td:nth-child(1) works.`

So converting it with same logic, it should look like:

```
//sport-match-grp[not(contains(@style, "display: none;"))]//*[contains(@class, 'match-pop-market')]//table[contains(@id, 'options_table')]//tbody//tr[contains(@id, 'mta_row')]//td[1]
```

This does not work.  I'm having trouble with: //*[contains(@class, 'match-pop-market')].  Removing this helps, but why does this work as a css but not as an xpath?

```
<sport-match-grp style="display: inline;">
<table id="options_table" class="mpm_teams style-scope match-pop-market">
<tr id="mta_row" class="style-scope match-pop-market"><td class="match-pop-market" style="width: 60%;">Panama</td><td class="match-pop-market mpm_teams_cell mpm_teams_cell_click" data-product="AWin" data-div="3.2" data-eventid="6238456"><span class="match-pop-market mpm_teams_bet_val">3.20</span></td><td class="match-pop-market mpm_teams_cell mpm_teams_cell_click" data-product="Draw" data-div="3" data-eventid="6238456" rowspan="2"><span class="match-pop-market mpm_teams_bet_val">3.00</span></td></tr>
```

I believe the answer should be as simple as that that selector is not above it so of course it should not work.

So this works:

```
//sport-match-grp[not(contains(@style, "display: none;"))]//*[contains(@class, 'match-pop-market')][contains(@id, 'options_table')]//tr[contains(@id, 'mta_row')]//td[1]
```

Note:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'match-pop-market')][contains(@id, 'options_table')]
```

Uh right... so `match-pop-market > #options_table` behaves near identically to the above where it gets elements that exists in match-pop-market.  Options_tables also exists so it works.  This clears things up for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I match on an attribute that contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-can-i-match-on-an-attribute-that-contains-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a recurring XPath problem. `contains` function have to be fixed when the search value is not the first char attribute value.

Try this instead :

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' match-pop-market ')]
```