# Xpath select by class and any other sub class

Tags: php, xpath

Is it possible to select elements with class values like this:

```
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
<div class="a d"></div>
<div class="a e"></div>
<div class="a f"></div>
```

I need select all of the div elements who's class attribute value has `a`...

I tried something like this:

```
$items = $xpath->query('//div[@class="a *"]');
```

I tried without `*`, but it also returned nothing.

What is the correct XPath to select these elements by their class attribute values?

Comment: is that a typo? `class"a b"` that class attribute is malformed, or just editing error in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As pointed out by `kjhughes`, this is a bad answer because it matches everything that has an `'a'` inside.**

You can try the `xpath` query `//div[contains(@class, "a")]` if you want to find any `div` that has the `class` attribute that contains `"a"`

Comment: You win, perfect...prrrrrrrrrrrrrrr, flawless victory! tks a lot!

Comment: Despite OP's elation, this is a bad answer  (-1) as it would match `class="bad"` too.  See [**Mads Hansen's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49889986/290085) or the [**duplicate link**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1390568/290085) for the right way to test whether `@class` attribute value contains a certain value.

Answer (score 2):

Pad the class attribute with leading and trailing spaces and look for "`a`":

`//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' a ')]`

That way it will match whether the "a" value is anywhere in the class attribute value, and won't match on false positives for things such as `class="baz"`

Comment: This variant should help in some other situation, and my too... tks too man.

Comment: This is the right answer, +1 (or see the [**duplicate link**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1390568/290085) for additional variations and discussion).