# Stop search after matching certain element (XPath)

Tags: xpath

I need to match elements with `block` and `result` until the first occurrence of the element with class `block` but NOT `result`.

XPath:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'result') and contains(@class ,'block')][following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'block') and not(contains(@class,
'result'))]]
```

Example 1 (works in this case):

```
<div class="block result"></div> <!-- match this -->
<div class="block result"></div> <!-- match this -->
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block result"></div> <!-- DONT match this -->
<div class="block result"></div> <!-- DONT match this -->
```

Example 2 (doesn't match anything here)

```
<div class="block result"></div> <!-- match this -->
<div class="block result"></div> <!-- match this -->
```

... so it doesn't matching anything in the second example. Can I make the following optional so it matches in both conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty, but should work...

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' block ') and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' result ') and not(preceding-sibling::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' block ') and not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' result '))])]
```

It should match divs with both the `block` and `result` classes but only if they don't have a preceding sibling div that contains a `block` class with no `result` class.

See answers in this question to see why I'm using `concat()`:

[How can I match on an attribute that contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-can-i-match-on-an-attribute-that-contains-a-certain-string)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

You can put in a List all which contain 'block' and after check with getAttribute("class") if contains "result" until not contain.

```
List<WebElement> aux = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class ,'block')]"));

for(WebElement a : aux) {

    if(a.getAttribute("class").contains("result")) {

        System.out.println(a.getText()); //Save in other list


    }else {

        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: `contains` is safe because the element may contain other classes. Also, ,I believe `/` for child, not siblings

Comment: As I know `[@class = 'block result]` match with `<div class="block result other1 other2"></div>`
P.S: I edited it. Try this new one.

Comment: No it won't. `=` means `is equal to`.

Comment: I have come with other solution. It work, but I don't know if it is ideal for you.