# Python and xpath: identify html tags with spaced attributes

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

Considering the following code:

```
<div class="tag1">
<div>
    <a class="tag11 tag12" href="http://www.example.com/file1" title="file1"><img class="tag2" src="http://www.example.com/img1.jpg" alt="textalt">linktext</a>
    <span class="tag3">.</span>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="tag11 tag12" href="http://www.example.com/file2" title="file2"><img class="tag2" src="http://www.example.com/img1.jpg" alt="textalt">linktext</a>
    <span class="tag3">.</span>
</div>
```

This is a **part** of a larger html page, which contains other `a` elements with other tags. However, I would like to refer **only** to the `a` elements whose class is `tag11 tag12` and to create a list containing all their `href` values. There is a space between `tag11` and `tag12`.

Using Python 3.5, `lxml` and `xpath`, here is a first attempt:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.example.com/page.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

atest = tree.xpath('//a[contains(@class='tag11 tag12')]')
```

but it doesn't work. Using single apices:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    buyers = tree.xpath('//a[contains(@class='tag11 tag12')]')
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using double apices:

```
tree.xpath('//a[contains(@class="tag11 tag12")]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 1587, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:61854)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:178516)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:177421)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid number of arguments
```

Also (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5449355)):

```
atest = tree.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "tag11") and contains(@class, "tag12")]')
```

an empty `atest` list is obtained.

How to correctly handle `a` elements whose `class` tag contains spaces?

---

I am using Python 3.5, `lxml` and `xpath` because I'm trying to learn these tools. So, there is no particular reason not to use BeautifulSoup, but I'm just looking for a specific solution for these listed tools, if any.

Comment: I'm not Python developer but you probably need to escape single quotation marks. Have you tried `'//a[@class = \'tag11 tag12\']'` ? or `tree.xpath('//a[contains(@class, \'tag11\') and contains(@class, \'tag12\')]')`

Comment: @derloopkat Thank you. The first one generates an error; the second one creates a list of (I guess) raw elements: `[<Element a at 0x7f3a47b5c6d8>, <Element a at 0x7f3a440e2818>]`. Not the actual `href` strings.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason for not using BeautifulSoup4? Here is a code snippet from my project:

```
import urllib.request             # You could use requests library as well   
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.example.com/page.html'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
         "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
         "Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"}

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(
                     urllib.request.Request(url, headers=header)),
                     'lxml')

links = list()
for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='tag1 tag2'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: I edited the question hopefully to answer you question. However, thank you for providing an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check this XPath: `'//a[@class="tag11 tag12"]/@href`'

```
from lxml import html

page = "<div class=\"tag1\"> <div> <a class=\"tag11 tag12\" href=\"http://www.example.com/file1\" title=\"file1\"><img class=\"tag2\" src=\"http://www.example.com/img1.jpg\" alt=\"textalt\">linktext</a> <span class=\"tag3\">.</span> </div> <div> <a class=\"tag11 tag12\" href=\"http://www.example.com/file2\" title=\"file2\"><img class=\"tag2\" src=\"http://www.example.com/img1.jpg\" alt=\"textalt\">linktext</a> <span class=\"tag3\">.</span> </div>"
tree = html.fromstring(page)
links = tree.xpath('//a[@class="tag11 tag12"]/@href')

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com/file1
http://www.example.com/file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach to play with multiple classes. It will return the required output if both of the `classes` are present:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

content = """
<div class="tag1">
<div>
    <a class="tag11 tag12" href="http://www.example.com/file1" title="file1"><img class="tag2" src="http://www.example.com/img1.jpg" alt="textalt">linktext</a>
    <span class="tag3">.</span>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="tag11 tag12" href="http://www.example.com/file2" title="file2"><img class="tag2" src="http://www.example.com/img1.jpg" alt="textalt">linktext</a>
    <span class="tag3">.</span>
</div>
"""
tree = fromstring(content)
for atest in tree.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "tag11") and contains(@class, "tag12")]'):
    print(atest.attrib['href'])
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com/file1
http://www.example.com/file2
```

Comment: My goal is "how to correctly handle `a` elements whose `class` tag contains spaces", with `xpath` in an html page. I tried to edit the question to be more clear and to give more context.

Comment: FYI, never use `multiple classes` (that you mentioned as space separarted) in a single expression because one or more classes may generate dynamically and your expression will be very much prone to break. The safer approach here will be to use `contains()` keyword as I've tried to show above. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've read this recommendation in other posts. In this specific case, being not the owner of the page, I can't correct this flaw. If I understand correctly, your approach identifies *all* the `a` elements with `multiple classes`, but in my case only the ones with `tag11 tag12` must be listed.