# XPath for class and other attribute values together?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

***PART A***

I'd like to select an HTML element by its attribute values. I'd like to be able to match *all* the attributes.

So an element `<a>` with the following attributes for example:

```
'href' => "https://twitter.com/JSTOR"
'target' => "_blank"
'class' => "icon-twitter twitter-styling icon-large"
'aria-label' => "Twitter - This link opens in a new window"
```

Is it like this:
//a[@href='https://twitter.com/JSTOR' AND @target='_blank' AND @class='icon-twitter twitter-styling icon-large' ...

So if I have n attributes, I need n-1 "AND"?

***PART B***

Also worth noting is the multiple values in "class". Can I simply have @class='classA classB classC' or should I @class='classA' AND @class='classB' AND @class='classC'?

***PART C***

Lastly, for the multiple values in "class", does the *order* matter? If the tag lists 'classA classB' and we use an xpath //a[@class='classB classA', will it still match?

**Please note I need an answer for XPath 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath illustrates all of the concepts of your three-part question:

```
//a[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' classA ')]
   [contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' classB ')]
   [contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' classC ')]
   [@href='https://twitter.com/JSTOR']
   [@target='_blank']
```

Notes:

- The `@class` tests prevent `classA` from matching `classAnt`.
- You can use `and` to join your conditions in a single predicate rather than compound predicates.

Answer (score 1):

> So if I have n attributes, I need n-1 "AND"?

Yes.

> Can I simply have `@class='classA classB classC'`

You can, but it will require exact match, including whitespace and order

> Lastly, for the multiple values in "class", does the order matter?

It does matter if you do equality match. There are ways around this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390680/450611)