# XPath expression to get a node and exclude a node within

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to get everything inside the div "entry" accept for the paragraph tag with the class = "metadata"

```html
<div class="entry">
    <p>The senator's lack of action on gun legislation is glaring after
       two mass shootings this weekend killed 31.</p>
    <p>McConnell has for months now been the plug halting nearly every piece 
       of legislation Democrats pass through the House, including gun 
       measures that enjoy bipartisan support.</p>
    <p class="metadata alt">
        <small>
            This entry was posted on Tuesday, August 6th, 2019 at 10:23 am
        </small>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath selects anything under your `div` with class `entry`.

Then uses `/*[not(@class="metadata alt")` which looks at all child nodes that do not have a class value of "metadata alt", which includes nodes which do not have a class attribute...

```
//div[@class="entry"]/*[not(@class="metadata alt")]
```

This gives two elements...

```
<p>The senator's lack of action on gun legislation is glaring after
       two mass shootings this weekend killed 31.</p>
<p>McConnell has for months now been the plug halting nearly every piece 
       of legislation Democrats pass through the House, including gun 
       measures that enjoy bipartisan support.</p>
```

If you want to check if the class attribute contains `metadata`, from [How can I match on an attribute that contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-can-i-match-on-an-attribute-that-contains-a-certain-string) ...

```
//div[@class="entry"]/*[not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' metadata '))]
```

The full code to test is...

```
$html = '<div class="entry">
    <p>The senator\'s lack of action on gun legislation is glaring after
       two mass shootings this weekend killed 31.</p>
    <p>McConnell has for months now been the plug halting nearly every piece 
       of legislation Democrats pass through the House, including gun 
       measures that enjoy bipartisan support.</p>
    <p class="metadata alt">
        <small>
            This entry was posted on Tuesday, August 6th, 2019 at 10:23 am
        </small>
    </p>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

$p = $xp->query('//div[@class="entry"]/*[not(@class="metadata alt")]');
foreach ($p as $out )   {
    echo $doc->saveHTML($out).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this idea is correct but using //div[@class='entry']/*[not(@class='metadata alt')] doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I've added the code I've tested with to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what your are looking for, the expression

```
//div[@class='entry']/p[position() = 1 to count(../p[not(@class="metadata alt")])]
```

selects

> The senator's lack of action on gun legislation is glaring after two mass shootings this weekend killed 31.The senator's lack of action on gun legislation is glaring after two mass shootings this weekend killed 31.
>   McConnell has for months now been the plug halting nearly every piece of legislation Democrats pass through the House, including gun measures that enjoy bipartisan support.

Comment: No, I want everything inside //div[@class='entry'] but not <p class="metadata alt">

Comment: @KarlHill - all the way through "bipartisan support"?

Comment: Yes, and there could potentially be more <p> tags in <div class="entry">.