# Select Element with specific class from multiple classes

Tags: html, xpath

If I have this DOM:

```
<div class="A others classes">

    other elements

    <div class="AB other classes"></div>

    other elements

</div>
```

I want to select the `div` with class `A`.

I have tried with `//div[contains(@class, 'A')]`, but also select the `div` with class `AB`.

How I can select just `div` with class `A`? I can't use other classes in xpath, because are dynamic added to element.

Comment: Another helpful duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-can-i-match-on-an-attribute-that-contains-a-certain-string

Comment: @DanielHaley: Thanks, added ahead of the original duplicate as it's better (albeit with a bit harder-to-find title).

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities are

1. Match with the space following `A`:

   ```
   //div[contains(@class, 'A ')]
   ```
2. Match `A` and exclude `AB` explicitly:

   ```
   //div[contains(@class, 'A') and not(contains(@class, 'AB'))]
   ```

Maybe this fits your needs.

Comment: There's an idiom to make such a differentiation more robustly.  See duplicate link.  (Your solution would select `div` elements with `class="xxxA "`, for example -- probably not desired.)